# RSA mpz_powm() in for-loop: seg fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, rsa, gmp

This is a follow-up question to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127204/rsa-gnu-mp-cannot-allocate-memory-size-1307836444/20129532) (now that the actual issue is different):

```
int main() 
{
    mpz_t p, q, n, phi_n, e, d; 
    mpz_inits(p, q, n, phi_n, e, d, NULL);

    generate_pq(p,q);
    compute_n(n,p,q);

    compute_phiN(phi_n,p,q);
    mpz_clear(p,q,NULL);

    select_e(e,phi_n);

    compute_d(d,e,phi_n);
    mpz_clear(phi_n);

    mpz_t* m;
    int size=0;
    store_m(m,size);

    mpz_t* c;
    encrypt(c,m,size,e,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the relevant functions:

```
void store_m(mpz_t m[], int& size) 
{ /* m = original message */
    printf("\nMessage: ");
    char* buffer = new char[128];
    cin.getline(buffer,128);
    size = strlen(buffer); //size = buffer
    m = new mpz_t[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        mpz_init(m[i]);
        mpz_set_ui(m[i],(int)buffer[i]);
    }
    delete buffer;
}

void encrypt(mpz_t*& c, mpz_t m[], const int size, 
                 const mpz_t e, const mpz_t n)
{ /* c = cipher */
    cout << "1" << endl;
    c = new mpz_t[size];
    cout << "2" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        cout << "3" << endl;
        mpz_init(c[i]);
        cout << "4" << endl;
        mpz_powm(c[i],m[i],e,n);
        cout << "5" << endl;
        mpz_clear(m[i]);
        cout << "6" << endl;
    } /* c = m^e(mod n) */
    cout << "7" << endl;
}
```

When I execute, the program goes into **encrypt()** but seg faults at the 4th cout.

Comment: Can you show `mpz_init`?

Comment: Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Nevermind, that doesn't seem to be the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember C++ is pass-by-value unless you explictly say you're passing by reference using the `&` operator.  In `store_m()` you are allocating and assigning to `m` inside the function.  That won't work since you're passing `m` by value.  As a result the `main()` function never sees the assignment to `m` since `store_m()` has only a local copy of `m`.  You are therefore passing an uninitialized variable to `encrypt()`.  Either allocate `m` in `main()` or declare `store_m()` like so:

`void store_m( mpt_t*& m, int& size);`

BTW: You're not segfaulting at the 4th `cout`.  You're segfaulting right after when the `encrypt()` function prepares to call `mpz_powm()`.  The actual crash is the dereference `m[i]` (since `m` is unitialized).

Comment: Not working. Every `mpz_t*` I initialized is now passed-by-ref. GMP documentation says mpz_t is 'effectively' passed-by-ref, so I didn't believe that was necessary.

Comment: "Effectively passed by ref" means the various mpz_* routines can modify the passed-in object. You still have to make sure the `m` in main() is both allocated and assigned after the store_m() call so the encrypt() function can use it. Post your modified code.

Comment: To fix your code make `m` in `store_m()` a local variable instead of an argument and have it `return m;`.  Then in `main()` do `m = store_m( size );`.  You'll see that fixes the problem.  That'll be easier than initializing `m` via an argument.

Comment: Be sure also that you remember to `delete m` after `encrypt()`. In this small program you don't need to since the program stops when `main()` returns but that's a horrible thing to rely on. Better to get in the habit of cleaning up after yourself.

Comment: Since I was having all that trouble passing the arguments, I just gutted `store_m()` and `encrypt()` and put their definitions in `main()`. Compiled and ran no problem. Thanks for all your help and info!!!